# NVMe SSD won't boot after fsck

Tags: boot, ssd, nvme

The other day my laptop showed up a black screen when started it up, asking me to run `fsck` manually. I did so, and at that time I was able to get in the OS.

Once I restarted the laptop, I was asked to run `fsck` manually again, but this time I had to run it with `-y` in order to answer yes to every prompt - they were too many this time.

After doing so, I was not able to boot into my SSD and Ubuntu anymore. 
The SSD is visible when I check the boot order of my BIOS, but it's not available anywhere else. And if I select it to boot from it, it shows a screen saying "No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key"

[image: BIOS boot option menu - SSD is listed]

What I mean by anywhere else: I've tried rEFInd, boot-repair, GParted and other options, using a Live USB, and each time I was unable to see the SSD which normally would be under `/dev/nvme0n1p1`

My specs:

HP Pavilion x360 - 15-cr0566nz

Toshiba KBG30ZMV256G NVMe 256g SSD

I am not very experienced with Linux. Any pointers much appreciated!

Comment: You should boot PC from live cd (like pendrive with latest ubuntu) and use SMART monitoring tools to check your ssd attributes for any indicators of failing disk. If it's not even visible, then it might be already faulty. So you will eventualy need to replace it or send it to warranty.

Comment: UEFI boot entries are stored in UEFI's NVRAM, so that does not mean drive is available. If Smart tools do not see drive check UEFI and drives that are attached. If not shown, check connections. But NVMe is screwed in and should not be an issue.

Comment: The SSD is at the moment only visible in the Boot Option menu of the BIOS. Using the Live CD and the Disk Utility, doesn't list the drive at all.